# Performance monitoring is not working on Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, firebase-performance

Recently I have tried to connect my mobile app to performance monitoring but I haven't got success with it.

I setup Xamarin.Android without any troubles but with iOS the things are sad(
On Firebase.PerformanceMonitoring page still present button 'Add SDK'.

In application output(iOS) I got these errors
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNxwu.jpg)

Does anyone have the solution for it?

As a guide I took [github](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/main/docs/Firebase/PerformanceMonitoring/GettingStarted.md)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You try to check if your Firebase installation library is installed correctly, and try to test whether this happens in a real device.